# Can't declare a variable in Oracle SQL(SQL Fiddle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlfiddle

When I run declare query, it always gives me errors.

```
DECLARE
   the_variable date;
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN("Start Date") INTO the_variable FROM "Employee_Master";
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 20: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
> "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not
> null range with default character.

I am not sure where is the problem.

Comment: looks like SQLFiddle doesn't support PL/SQL. It fails even on simple `begin null; end;`

Comment: huh, but it works if I add `/` in the next line

Comment: and it works if I put all pl/sql block in  one block, ie: `declare dt date; begin dt:=date'2020-01-01'; end;` with `/` in next line

Answer (score 2):

Works OK for me:

```
SQL> create table "Employee_Master" ("Start Date" date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into "Employee_Master" values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2    the_variable date;
  3  begin
  4    select min("Start Date") into the_variable
  5      from "Employee_Master";
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Though, **why**, oh, why are you making your life miserable? Avoid double quotes while working with Oracle. If you do that, you always have to reference tables (and columns) using double quotes and matching letter case **exactly** as during creation process.

By default, Oracle stores *everything* as uppercase, but you can reference those objects any way you want (upper, lower, mixed case - doesn't matter). But, with double quotes, as I've said - exact matching is required.

---

By the way, screenshot you attached shows a lot of *nothing* and just a little bit of *something*. Couldn't you have taken a better screenshot?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for the screenshot, and I removed it. The col name is fixed already and has a space within it, so I had to use double-quotes. I am using SQL Fiddle oracle, but it always gives me the error. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4

Answer (score 1):

On the SQL Fiddle website, you need to tell it that you are going to be using PL/SQL and a statement will be ended with a `/` terminator (and not by a `;` semi-colon). To do this you need to click on the "Query Terminator" button (right of the "Run SQL" and "Edit Fullscreen" buttons) and change it from <kbd>`[;]`</kbd> to <kbd>`[/]`</kbd>.

Then it will work:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c10c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee_Master ( Start_Date DATE );
    
INSERT INTO Employee_Master ( Start_Date ) VALUES ( SYSDATE );
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
DECLARE
   the_variable date;
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN(Start_Date) INTO the_variable FROM Employee_Master;
END;
/
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c10c/1/0)**: